# get product name for the order in my dashboard

Tags: magento-2.1, product, orders, custom-options, dashboard

I am working on magento 2.1.8. In the `my dashboard` There are orders listing. But i want the product name of that order also.

right now product name could be shown by clicking on the view all list. This order is coming from `recent.phtml`. I also tried to get the product name from. `order>items>renderer>default.html` The code i copy was this.

```
<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
```

how ever i am still not able to get this. Can any body help me in this regard.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fetch order Items using `getAllVisibleItems()` function of order object.

You can print the Ordered Items name in `recent.phtml` using the below code in `$_orders` foreach loop:

```
foreach ($_order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
     echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName());
}
```

Hope this help !!

Comment: works like a charm. just a last question is it possible to add the wish list in this section ?

Comment: Yes it is possible to add wishlist block here. for this you need to add new block in xml for wishlist on dashboard. You can ask separate question for this if face any issue.

Comment: Its good thanks but have a question: when i have 3 items in one order id it shows like item1 item2 item3. i want to show item1</br> item2</br> item3... with image of product. any help?